# Extend Swagger Doc of REST Endpoints of another codebase

Tags: java, swagger

In one of our projects we are having a dependency to a module from another team's codebase that includes a Spring REST Service. This service provides some endpoints, including one that offers to search for some objects based on some query parameters. In its constructor, this REST Service has a dependency to a, lets say, `ObjectSearchService` implementation.

In our team, we are extending this Object and we've implemented our own `ObjectSearchService` in order to search by several other query parameters that fit our extension of Object.

The problem now is that we would like to show these additional query parameters in the swagger documentation of the REST endpoint, but it does not reside in our code base.

Is there some possibility to overwrite/extend the documentation for that specific endpoint in Swagger?

Comment: Rather than you describing the code it would be easier if you just showed it ;)